# Will this Arduino module work with Raspberry Pi 3?

Tags: gpio, arduino, lirc, compatibility

I know Arduino modules aren't generally compatible, but this looks like it could be. It's the **Keyes KY-005 infrared transmitter**.

There doesn't appear to be a data sheet anywhere online (and that's even [a question on Stack Exchange](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/136421/datasheet-for-keyes-ir-transmitter-ky-005-wanted)).

Its outputs are signal, 5v, and ground. Here's the best info I could get on it:

```
Operating Voltage:  5V
Forward Current:  30 ~ 60 mA
Power Consumption:  90mW
Operating Temperature:  -25°C to 80°C [-13°F to 176°F]
```

Could I not plug the 5v into the Raspberry Pi's 5v output on the GPIO board, the signal to GPIO-17, and ground to ground?

This is how it looks:

[image]

My goal is to output a strong enough IR signal to turn on a TV from a normal distance (a meter or so is fine). I got a weak IR LED to work with LIRC, plugged directly into the Pi's GPIO, but of course this signal was too weak.

I want to avoid a breadboard with resistors and transistors, etc. This appears to be the standard Raspberry Pi solution, which I hope to avoid:

[image]

Comment: If you want anyone to answer post a link to the data sheet of the module. If you read this it would probably answer your question.

Comment: I would if I could. This is actually a question on Stack Exchange: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/136421/datasheet-for-keyes-ir-transmitter-ky-005-wanted

Comment: The resource at Tkkrlab is as close to a data sheet as you'll get: [Arduino KY-005 Infrared emission sensor module - TkkrLab](https://tkkrlab.nl/wiki/Arduino_KY-005_Infrared_emission_sensor_module "Arduino KY-005 Infrared emission sensor module - TkkrLab"). It agrees with the numbers you used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Confirmed** - **Yes**, this will work with the Raspberry Pi, and LIRC.

1. Plug it into the appropriate GPIO ports (3.3V, ground, and GPIO 17), with the Pi off.
2. Updated "`/etc/modules`" to include:

   `lirc_rpi gpio_out_pin=17`
3. Recorded IR from a separate IR receiver (on port 18)

   `sudo /etc/init.d/lirc stop`

   `irrecord -H default -d /dev/lirc0 -f NEW.conf`
4. Copied the LIRC file saved in `NEW.conf` to the end of "`/etc/lirc/lircd.conf`"
5. Send/blast IR signals with the Raspberry Pi:

   `service lirc start`

   `irsend SEND_ONCE {remote's name here} KEY_POWER`

This sends a strong signal from across my living room.

I do appreciate the learning aspect of making your own breadboard solution, sometimes even hobbyists just want the end result. This is a much simpler solution than using resistors, transistors, etc.

Comment: Did you have to use any additional components while connecting the sensor to the Raspberry Pi?

Comment: No. I simply plugged each pin into the appropriate GPIO location on the Pi. Of course be 100% sure you're plugging things into the correct location, and the Pi is off while doing this.

Comment: I have a similar module but with a 1 kOhm SMD resistor pre soldered (R1 on your picture). And it works well with a 3.3V and 5V from Raspberry Pi direct connection.

Answer (score 2):

Are there any other components on the module? From the [dx.com page](http://www.dx.com/p/38khz-ir-infrared-transmitter-module-for-arduino-135040) it looks like it's a bare LED. The 5V connection may not go anywhere.

IR LEDs are pretty current-hungry, and that's why the examples have a transistor to beef up the current. You may get a faint flicker connecting it directly (most cellphone cameras detect IR from LEDs quite well, btw), but you might not get the range you need.

Comment: actually it seems there are [other versions of this board with a transistor](http://khmermaker.com/image/cache/catalog/products/module%20KY-005%20For%20Arduino%20Branch-%20infrared%20emission%20sensor/module-KY-005-For-Arduino-Branch--infrared-emission-sensor-600x500.png), but the one in the picture does not have it.

Answer (score 1):

The linked device should work.

The only question mark is whether the Pi's GPIO high of 3V3 would be seen as a high input by the signal pin of that 5V device.  It should be (at least I do not remember anyone saying they couldn't control the device from the Pi).